Kubernetes-Traefik how set up revers-proxy to external domain name?
I need requests for a specific URL to be reverse-proxy to a server outside the cluster using the domain name of the external server. Example:
https://my.cluster.com/v2 /... -> https://my.outsidedomain.com/v2 /...
My example:
Ingress:
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
metadata:   
  name: external-ingress
  annotations: 
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: simple-issuer 
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik 
  rules:     
  - host: my.cluster.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /v2/
        backend:
          service:
            name: external-service                 
            port:                   
              name: https   
  tls:     
    - hosts: 
      - my.cluster.com
      secretName: secret-cert

Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: external-service
spec:
ports:
- name: https
  port: 443
  targetPort: https
type: ExternalName
externalName: my.outsidedomain.com

But this dont work. I tried many more different options and they didn't help. There were designs with IngressRoute and Endpoint, but without success.

have you tried adding allowExternalNameServices: true to Traefik configuration? https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v2/#k8s-externalname-service
